# RSS Reader: UITableView displays data very slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rss

I'm loading data from an rss feed and displaying the titles in a `UITableview`.
I'm using `BlockRSSParser`, to quickly get the required fields - [Here](https://github.com/tiboll/BlockRSSParser)

I'm using `NSLog` to track when the data is received. It takes around 20 secs before the `UITableView` displays the data, after receiving it.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setTitle:@"Loading..."];
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/"]];
    [RSSParser parseRSSFeedForRequest:req success:^(NSArray *feedItems) {
        [self setTitle:@"Blogs"];
        [self setDataSource:feedItems];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        RSSItem *item = [dataSource objectAtIndex:2];
        NSLog(@"loaded cell %@", [item title]);

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Notice the comment in this code. It gets executed quickly and shows me one of the title of the blog post.

But then for the next 20 secs, nothing is displayed before the following method finally kicks in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    RSSItem *item = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"loaded cell %@", [item title]);

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:item.title];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:item.title];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    NSString *theTitle = [item title];
    cell.textLabel.text = theTitle;

    return cell;
}
```

The comment in this code is executed after 20 secs. What is the reason behind this large delay?
I have tried using different feed urls from different sites. Still the same output.

Comment: I would say that calling tableview reloadData  at viewdidload it's not a good idea, do reloadData and the request somewhere at viewdidapear or viewdidlayouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute all UI-related tasks on the main-queue. Sample code below might need some adjustments to get the variables into the block.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setTitle:@"Loading..."];
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/"]];
    [RSSParser parseRSSFeedForRequest:req success:^(NSArray *feedItems) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setTitle:@"Blogs"];
            [self setDataSource:feedItems];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

        RSSItem *item = [dataSource objectAtIndex:2];
        NSLog(@"loaded cell %@", [item title]);

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Comment: As I said: all UI-related tasks have to happen on the main-queue. UIKit is not thread-safe. The documentation emphasizes this everywhere. However, the people who made it obviously put some effort into making it still do what you want - just a lot slower.